# MsgBox Function does not work

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a subroutine that worked correctly when I had only the MsgBox function "Quest". The end result of the procedure is to send an email containing one of three texts plus attachments. I have now added another MsgBox: "FirstTime". My problem is that the procedure does not ask either of the questions in the functions but acts as if it assumes that the answer to "FirstTime" is 6. If I change Line 6 to "If FirstTime = 7" then the email has no text at all. I tried some attempts to work around - separating bits out into separate functions and using Select Case, but to no avail - the same problems occur. I could build my own function (with three questions built in but I'd prefer to stick with MsgBox) Here's the relevant part of my procedure:

```vb
Dim Quest As Integer
Dim FirstTime As Integer

FirstTime = MsgBox("Send as a first-timer?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Issue Forms")

If FirstTime = 6 Then
    Txt = Txt3
Else
    If IsNull(Forms!frmClient.RulesAgreed) Then
        Quest = MsgBox("Do you want to send the SLA?", vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton1 + vbYesNo, "Service Level Agreement")
        If Quest = 6 Then
            Txt = Txt2
            Forms!frmClient.SLASent = Date
        Else
            Txt = Txt1
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Have you set a break point and stepped through the code to confirm the statements you expect are run when `FirstTime = 6` (*vbYes*)?  Note you can also watch the values of your variables as you step through the code.

Comment: Not yet. Thanks - I will.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying that your first message box doesn't show up at all?

Comment: No message boxes show up at. I thinK I said  that the procedure does not ask either of the questions in the functions but acts as if it assumes that the answer to "FirstTime" is 6.

Comment: OK, what happens if you put your cursor on MsgBox and hit Shift-F2 to go to its definition?

Comment: I just get the Object Browser All Libraries - no particular item.

Answer (score 1):

I have found in another procdure, connected to the one I have posted, a SendKeys procedure. I believe these are to be avoided. Having removed it my code now works as it should. Had I posted all of my relevant code (a lot of space - which is why I didn't) I'm sure someone would have put their finger on the spot. I'm now going to remove all SendKeys regardless - I'll deal with any probs as and when.

Answer (score 0):

Your Else-If is probably wrong. And do use the constants:

```vb
Dim Quest As vbMsgBoxResult
Dim FirstTime As vbMsgBoxResult

FirstTime = MsgBox("Send as a first-timer?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Issue Forms")

If FirstTime = vbYes Then
    Txt = Txt3
ElseIf IsNull(Forms!frmClient.RulesAgreed) Then
    Quest = MsgBox("Do you want to send the SLA?", vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton1 + vbYesNo, "Service Level Agreement")
    If Quest = vbYes Then
        Txt = Txt2
        Forms!frmClient.SLASent = Date
    Else
        Txt = Txt1
    End If
Else
    ' User answered No to firsttime and RulesAgreed is not null.
End If
```

End If

Comment: Just tried this and it makes no difference. MsgBox Functions did not ask questions.

Comment: Then you must adjust your logic - as I commented in-line.

Comment: Don't understand. What comments in-line? I believe I have done everything you said.

Comment: You probably hit: ' User answered No to firsttime and RulesAgreed is not null.

Comment: How could I when it's commented out? 'Probably'??

Comment: It is not commented out - it is a comment for your information. You can insert a new code line and either call a third messagebox, or assign a fixed text: Txt = Txt4. Or you must adjust your logic.

Comment: It does have ' in front so if I copy your coding it IS commented out. So is this what you actually mean: Dim Quest As vbMsgBoxResult
Dim FirstTime As vbMsgBoxResult

FirstTime = MsgBox("Send as a first-timer?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Issue Forms")

If FirstTime = vbYes Then
    Txt = Txt3
ElseIf IsNull(Forms!frmClient.RulesAgreed) Then
    Quest = MsgBox("Do you want to send the SLA?", vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton1 + vbYesNo, "Service Level Agreement")
    If Quest = vbYes Then
        Txt = Txt2
        Forms!frmClient.SLASent = Date
    Else
        Txt = Txt1
    End If

Comment: It is only a code line you can comment out. A comment is a comment. I put the line to tell you, that you end here if the user answers no to firsttime and RulesAgreed is Null. If so, nothing happens. So either, at this point, insert code for something to happen, or adjust the function so this situation does not happen.